# IOS: move an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation

In my app I want to move a little UIImageView with inside a .png; this is a little insect and I want to simulate his flight. At example I want that this png do when it move an inverted eight as the infinite simbol  ∞

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use CoreAnimation. You can subclass a view, create a subview for the insect, and then assign an animation to it, following a defined path.

Your UIImageView could be animated. If it's a fly, you can do a few frames for wing moves:

```
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:..., nil];

insect.animationImages = images;
insect.animationDuration = ??;
insect.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[insect startAnimating];
```

Then set an init frame for the insect:

```
insect.frame = CGRectMake(-120, 310, [[images objectAtIndex:0] size].width, [[images objectAtIndex:0] size].height);
```

And then define the path:

```
CGMutablePathRef aPath;
CGFloat arcTop = insect.center.y - 50;
aPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(aPath, NULL, insect.center.x, insect.center.y);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(aPath, NULL, insect.center.x, arcTop, 240, -100, 490, 360);

CAKeyframeAnimation* arcAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"position"];
arcAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
[arcAnimation setDuration: 4.5];
[arcAnimation setAutoreverses: NO];
arcAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
arcAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth; 
[arcAnimation setPath: aPath];
CFRelease(aPath);
[insect.layer addAnimation: arcAnimation forKey: @"position"];
```

I leave how to do the infinite loop path up to you :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm not able to do a loop path, can you help me?

Comment: Take a look to this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html // You must write a path using two semicircles and two lines (at least for a simpler version of ∞). In this image: http://twitpic.com/6yynco each colored line represents a path line that needs to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you were to be moving things around, I'd suggest using [UIView animate...]. However, you want something to move on a complex, curvy path. So instead, I'd suggest coming up with an equation that gives the (x,y) for the insect as a function of time, and then start an NSTimer with a fairly small time interval, and every time you get an update, move the insect (perhaps using [UIView animate...]).

Another way to go is to use a 2-d animation framework such as cocos2d - then, you can get an 'update' call linked to the frame refresh rate, inside of which you update the position of your insect using the same equation as from above.